# Passing Type Into Lambda Function In C++ Template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, g++, clang++

I am trying to use `std::transform` in template function. Because there are various types which need to be handled by the template function, the key part is the design of the lambda function in `std::transform`. I want to pass the base type of the iterable `T` to construct a lambda function. The experimental code here use `typename std::iterator_traits<T::iterator>::value_type` and [it compile successfully with gcc 10.2 and MSVC 19.27 but failed with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/799qK6).

After I replaced

`typename std::iterator_traits<T::iterator>::value_type`

into

`typename std::iterator_traits<typename T::iterator>::value_type`

[the problem seems to be solved](https://godbolt.org/z/rsMh8a). However, I am not sure whether this is the correct usage or not. Moreover, if there is any other better way to do this, please let me know.

```
template<typename T>
concept ElementSummable = requires(T x)
{
    x.at(0) + x.at(0);
};

template<typename T>
concept Iterable = requires(T x)
{
    x.begin();      // must have `x.begin()` 
    x.end();        // and `x.end()` 
};

template<class T> requires Iterable<T> && ElementSummable<T>
static T Foo(const T _input);

template<class T> requires Iterable<T> && ElementSummable<T>
static inline T Foo(const T _input)
{
    T returnObject = _input;
    std::transform(_input.begin(), _input.end(), returnObject.begin(),
        [](typename std::iterator_traits<T::iterator>::value_type element)->typename std::iterator_traits<T::iterator>::value_type
        {
            return element + 1;         //  For example
        }
    );
    return returnObject;
}

int main()
{
    long double number = 1;
    std::vector<decltype(number)> testVector1;
    testVector1.push_back(number);
    testVector1.push_back(number);

    std::cout << Foo(testVector1).at(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can just use auto for the parameter and don't need to specify the return type at all

Comment: @AlanBirtles Do you mean something like this `[](auto element)->auto` ?

Comment: Yes, though you don't need to specify the return type at all

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for the suggestion. However, I still want to know how to specify the type correctly in this structure.

Comment: You already have the correct type, you have to put typename before template dependant types, clang is just more rigorous than others in enforcing the standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the rigidity of `CLang` compilers with respect to the standard.

The problem is not the type(that is correct), the problem is that you have to put typename before template dependant types.

However the best solution is to use [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) to let the compiler deduce the type itself.